# Microsoft Visual Foxpro Syntax

Tags: c#, foxpro, visual-foxpro

I'm facing a weird issue, I'm running a query in the VFP9 command window, and it's working fine. But the same query in VFP7 command is throwing me an error with syntax.

Query

```
SELECT 
    a.Prov_Site, Office, a.billNum, a.invoicDate, a.TotalCharg, price 
FROM 
    invoices AS a 
LEFT JOIN 
   ( SELECT billNum, SUM(price) as Price FROM Items GROUP BY billNum) AS b 
ON a.billNum= b.billNumWHERE a.TotalCharg <> b.price
```

I am running the same query through C# code with VFP9 drivers installed, I am getting exception with syntax.

Can someone help me on this?

Thanks,
Sach

Comment: b.billNumWHERE - whitespace missing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

VFP 7 definitely doesn't support derived tables, so this query won't work there. From C#, are you using ODBC or OLE DB. The VFP ODBC drivers haven't been updated since VFP 6 and thus also don't support derived tables.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT a.prov_site, a.office, a.billnum, a.invoicdate, a.totalcharg, b.price 
FROM invoices AS a LEFT JOIN 
   (SELECT billnum, SUM(price) as price FROM items GROUP BY billnum) AS b 
ON a.billnum = b.billnum WHERE a.totalcharg <> b.price
```

Comment: Oleg, My applogies, White space is present in query whihc I ran, But When i m posting the questions I missed it. But its not working.